# How to identify when SAP GUI Scripting doesn't enter a transaction with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, sap-gui

What's up everyone,

I'm coding a program with VBA that get an information on SAP GUI, but sometimes SAP GUI doesn't enter the transaction and I want to identify when this happens.

```
'Getting the winding code
session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "/ncs15"
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtRC29L-DATUV").SetFocus
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtRC29L-DATUV").Text = ""
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/chkRC29L-DIRKT").Selected = True
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtRC29L-MATNR").Text = Worksheets("Barramentos").Range("C" & j)
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/chkRC29L-DIRKT").SetFocus
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[5]").press
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtRC29L-WERKS").Text = Worksheets("Barramentos").Range("I" & j)
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtRC29L-WERKS").SetFocus
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtRC29L-WERKS").caretPosition = 4
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[8]").press
```

**Here I want to know when SAP can enter the transaction or not**

I've tried using Chat GPT.

Comment: Apart from my answer : What do you mean with _I want to know when SAP can enter the transaction or not_- I am asking because this sentence could imply that certain conditions have to be met before you can start the transaction. Is that right or did your command of English lead me down the garden path?

Comment: Right, sometimes I enter a "material code" to see the project that this material is linked, but when there isn't the "link" between the material and the project it returns an error message and it doens't enter the transaction.

Comment: That is a different story then. You are in the transaction, the transaction tells you there is no data (in a nutshell) and you get an error message telling that more or less. You can check if you get an error in the statusbar.

Comment: I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can check that with the following code

```
Set SessionInfo = Session.Info
Debug.Print SessionInfo.Transaction
```

**Update**: Per the OP's comment this might be what is needed.

You can check for the type of a message in the status bar. If it is E then you've got an error.

```
If session.findById("wnd[0]/sbar").MessageType= "E" Then
  ' Whatever you want to do here for instance leave
   Exit Sub

End If
```